# TimeoutExpired when using EF6 MainContextDropInitializer on SQL Azure

Tags: database, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a database on SQL Azure, when I run automated unit tests I try to drop the DB and recreate it.

The constructor for the context is:

```
public MainContext(bool dropDB)
            : base("Main")
        {

            Database.CommandTimeout = 300;
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(new MainContextDropInitializer());

            this.Database.Connection.StateChange += Connection_StateChange;
        }
```

However when trying to execute the code I keep getting the following error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

The DB itself is quite small so setting a command timeout of 300 should be sufficient. Interestingly this issue only occurred since we upgrade the Azure DB to v12.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx? It talks about how you can use a sqlazure execution strategy that does transient fault handling and retries.